# Using multiple wildcards in path to run command on all files in directory

Tags: bash, wildcards

I'm trying to run a for loop that copies all files in a directory and then place them in a backup directory. There are multiple sub-directories with varying names so I thought I should use multiple wildcards so I didn't have to list all of them out and add another for loop in. This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="/home/users/data/*"

for file in $DIR
do
        cp "$file"/**/**/*.txt* "$DIR"/backup/"$file"
done
```

When I run it though the script can't go into the sub directories and thinks the directory is

`/directory1/**/**/*.txt*`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: try `shopt -s globstar`.  then a single `**` should be enough: eg. `/dir/**/*.txt`

Comment: @mosvy hmm okay that's what I need, but I seem to be getting an error still 
For example the script says it "cannot create regular file 
``/home/users/data/*backup//home/users/data/S036_20181002’``   Is there something with the $file part at the end of my destination path ``"$DIR"/backup/"$file"``?

Comment: Wildcards in quotes won't expand.

Comment: Is what you want to do very different from indiscriminatingly copying the whole of `/home/users/data` to `/home/users/data/backup` (minus the `backup` directory itself)?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to duplicate `/home/users/data` under `/home/users/data/backup`:

```
rsync -ai --exclude=/backup/ /home/users/data/ /home/users/data/backup
```

This would also exclude the `backup` directory itself from getting copied when rerunning the command.  Note that the source directory (and the directory in the exclude pattern) should have slashes at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use `find` here:

```
for FILE in $DIR
do
    find $DIR -iname '*.txt' -exec cp -fv {} ${DIR}/backup/${FILE} \;
done
```

You can add `--parents` option to `cp` if you want to preserve directory structure.